# Awk: print between patterns in the same line and reverse the order of matched string

Tags: sorting, parsing, awk

I've got an application service's log file and I'm trying to extract the stack trace dumped in there by one of its child processes. The stack traces have a completely different pattern from the usual log files.

**Usual webapp log file entries:**

```
2020-03-26 08:31:05.000 : INFO : (18582) : (SERVICE) : MSG_1234 : Process id 98765. Standard output and error:
```

**Stack trace's example:**

```
7f318820d000-7f318a106000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:10002]
7f318a106000-7f318a107000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
```

I need to extract the stack traces, which I'm able to do. The problem with the stack traces is that they are dumped in reverse order. Each dumped block is ordered, but the blocks are dumped in reverse order.

Here is an example of how I'm extracting the blocks (NOTE: start and stop patterns are in the same line):

```
echo "STOP message START
five
six
STOP message START
three
four
STOP message START
one
two
STOP message" | awk '/START/ {flag=1; next} flag; /STOP/ {flag=0}'
```

This is the output:

```
five
six
three
four
one
two
STOP message
```

Although, I'd like to get this:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

I can live with the last "STOP message" matched, but I need to have the blocks in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with this to number each block and the lines within each block as you find them then you can afterwards sort the lines however you like using `sort` and then remove the numbers you added using `cut`:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '/STOP/{lineNr=0} lineNr{print blockNr, lineNr++, $0} /START/{blockNr++; lineNr=1}' file
1       1       five
1       2       six
2       1       three
2       2       four
3       1       one
3       2       two
```

e.g.:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '/STOP/{lineNr=0} lineNr{print blockNr, lineNr++, $0} /START/{blockNr++; lineNr=1}' file |
    sort -k1,1nr -k2,2n
3       1       one
3       2       two
2       1       three
2       2       four
1       1       five
1       2       six

$ awk -v OFS='\t' '/STOP/{lineNr=0} lineNr{print blockNr, lineNr++, $0} /START/{blockNr++; lineNr=1}' file |
    sort -k1,1nr -k2,2n | cut -f3-
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

Comment: This is working. The only thing I had to change was the `sort` syntax from `sort -n -k1,1r -k2,2` to `sort -k1,1nr -k2,2n`. For some reason it wasn't sorting the numeric fields `>9` properly with just one `-n` at the beginning. Do you know why?

Comment: No, but I find the `sort` options syntax pretty unintuitive so maybe that's just how you have to write the command when using specific key field numbers, idk. I'll update my answer since we know that works.

Comment: Hmm, the result of a quick test of `seq 15 | sort -k1,1` implies that when you add any option to the keys (e.g. `-k1,1r`) it overrides all of the global options. So `seq 15 | sort -n -k1,1` works but `seq 15 | sort -n -k1,1r` doesn't and you have to use `seq 15 | sort -k1,1rn` instead. That's annoying.

Comment: You just have to match the start/end markers in whatever order is required to print those lines or not. If you do `/START/{f=1} f{print} /STOP/{f=0}` then `f` is set when the lines containing START and STOP are seen and so they are printed. Compare with each of `/STOP/{f=0} /START/{f=1} f{print}`, `/STOP/{f=0} f{print} /START/{f=1}`, etc. - just order the 3 blocks to set/clear `f` appropriately based on which of the start/stop lines you want printed.

Comment: In my first attempt to solve this i was matching `START` first, skipping the current line and printing the following lines up to (inclusive) the line containing `STOP`. In your answer, apart from adding the very clever `LineNr` and `blockNr`, you are reversing the match: i.e. `STOP` first, `START` after. I understand why you are doing it. Although, I'd like to understand whether there is a pattern in this way of coding. Do you always try to match the first match, no matter whether it's the start/stop pattern?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but I think the answer is "no"? You may be overthinking this, it's very simple - when trying to print text between start/end markers you always have 3 blocks of code: block A to set the "found" flag, block B to print the current line when the flag is set, and block C to clear the flag. Just arrange those 3 blocks in whatever order gives you the output you want for the lines that contain the start/end markers: A B C or A C B or B C A or whatever.